# How to automatically clear the terminal before reverse search?

Tags: shell, zsh, command-history

I was wondering if it is possible to run the `clear` command automatically when I initiate a reverse search with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.

I am familiar with the `precmd` function in zsh, but do not know how to limit it to a subset of commands without slowing down the sell.
One possible solution would be to add an `if` condition in `precmd` for detecting reverse search, although I am not sure what the condition should be for `history-incremental-search-backward`.

Answer (score 3):

```
function my-history-incremental-search-backward {
    zle clear-screen
    zle history-incremental-search-backward
}
zle -N my-history-incremental-search-backward
bindkey "^r" my-history-incremental-search-backward
```

We add a custom incremental search function that first clears the screen (you could also run `clear` but that looked ugly and then does not redraw the prompt if you <kbd>control+c</kbd> out of the search) and then runs the real `history-incremental-search-backward`.

Alternatively, you could redefine the `history-incremental-search-backward` widget with:

```
function history-incremental-search-backward {
  zle clear-screen
  zle .$WIDGET
}
zle -N history-incremental-search-backward
```

So you don't even need to rebind to all the keys the widget was already bound to.

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution. I added these lines to my `~/.zshrc` but did not get the desired effect. I will continue to work on it and share updates later.

Comment: `autoload` does not resolve the issue. You are right. I made sure the snippet was near the end of the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the solutions mentioned in this post work for me.